# OpenCV 3.4.3 says that SIFT is patented. Any other way to implement SIFT in python for free?

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am getting the following error when I want to use SIFT in OpenCV in python:

```
OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'
```

I have installed opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python and both of them have the exact same version. I checked another post with a similar problem and it turned out to be caused by conflicting versions, but the versions I have installed are the same. Somewhere I read that opencv-contrib-python does not offer some packages that are non-free anymore. If that's true, then what other options do I have to use SIFT in python for free?

Comment: I common alternative that is implemented in OpenCV is ORB... You can take a look to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/what-are-some-free-alternatives-to-sift-surf-that-can-be-used-in-commercial-app). You may use SIFT for non-comercial apps as far as I remember. And you can use the one of OpenCV, just that you need to make sure the module is compiled. How did you install OpenCV?

Comment: @api55 Thank you for your answer. I'm not looking for an alternative to SIFT, I'm looking for an alternative to OpenCV. I'm using SIFT for a university project and I must use SIFT only. I installed OpenCV using site-packages in PyCharm. I didn't compile it on my own. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. In recent python versions you need to install opencv-contrib for non-free modules.... I think for python the package is `opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: @api55  Thanks. But I have installed opencv-contrib-python. That error is thrown by opencv-contrib actually. :(

Comment: oh, true, I didn't see it... maybe it is not on with the current version :( My only solution left is either find wheel file that has it or compile it from sources

Comment: @api55 Thanks. But where could I find a wheel file that has SIFT? :(

Comment: I am not sure if a previous version may work... I installed mine with pip (version 3.4.0) and it is included. To generate this wheel files take a look to the [github page](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) of the script that generates the opecv-python and contrib packages... I think that is the easiest way, just remmeber to add the non free option.

Comment: try these .. pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17 , pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17